# How can I manage (or disregard) my feelings effectively while dealing with a difficult boss?

Tags: work-environment, asia

I’ve long worked for a startup owner, who was once my respected mentor. He’s become a difficult, even unprofessional, boss, enforcing abrupt policy changes, publicly criticizing and belittling employees, including me, and demanding unpaid extra work. I’ve been suppressing my feelings and considering quitting and publicly reviewing him and the startup - yes I have personal grudge against him, but I needed the job, so I’ve tried to remain professional and emotionally detached to avoid burning bridges, as he claims to have significant connections in the industry (think CEOs, directors of Big Four banks).

Lately, he’s implemented cost-cutting measures like pay cuts, increased workloads, and implied bonus cuts claiming the business is not doing well while he keeps his salary the same. He also expects us to be available for calls at any time for any reason. This has made it harder for me to stay detached and disrupted my personal life and messed up my mental health because I keep thinking and be upset about all of his nonsense. I confronted him in a team's group chat out of frustration, which likely damaged our relationship already as he seemed to start nitpicking me at work on the same day I confronted him. I’m planning to quit in a few months, but until then, how can I effectively detach and endure this environment? Or the only good choice is that I just quit and publicly review him?

Comment: Yes, do quit and find a new job. No point in waiting a few months. No, don't wash your dirty laundry in public and try public reviews. Focus all your energy on the future and let the past be the past. It can't be changed.

Comment: By a few months I mean two-three months because I don't want to forfeit the end-year bonus, which won't be paid until Feb because they don't want people to just get the bonus and quit (I don't really see the logic since if they quit they quit anyways, but it's explained to me that way). Also I estimate that's how long it takes to find a new job / wrap up everything

Comment: What makes you think there will be a bonus when the company is not doing well?

Comment: In which State/Country is this located in?

Comment: If you have to work with him: set the history aside, set your feelings about him aside, and focus on what is happening Right Now. Part of being a professional is being able to work with the partners we've got even if we don't like them, and carrying a grudge block attempting to address current needs. If you can't achieve that, walk away. "The customer is not always right. The customer is the one holding the money. Would you rather be right, or paid?" Either is justifiable.

Comment: For what it's worth, the same basic answer applies to dealing with difficult employees. If you aren't ready to get rid of them, focus on getting them to do the right things _now_.

Answer (score 8):

> so I’ve tried to remain professional and emotionally detached to avoid burning bridges, as he claims to have significant connections in the industry (think CEOs, directors of Big Four banks).

Keep your self-respect. If his connections were as strong as he claims, these people would be giving him money or loans. In either case, it doesn't matter what his "friends" you've never met, and will probably never meet, supposedly think of you. It really doesn't. It's a humongous World out there. Also, constantly badmouthing your employees to your "powerful friends" is like constantly badmouthing your employer. It makes whoever say those things look bad in front of those people. And my bet is that he's far more worried about tarnishing his image in front of them than he's motivated to badmouth you to them. In either case, it wouldn't matter anyway.

If his startup is running out of runway, it's a sign that the company is close to going out of business. Take a look at it from his perspective. Don't you think he knows that cutting your pay, demanding unpaid overtime, and suddenly delaying the year-end bonus is going to destroy his company? He knows this, but he's doing it anyway because he knows the company is about to fold. Because if he was really serious about trying to save his company, he would be taking the biggest pay cut and he would be honest with all of you. The fact that he hasn't taken any of these steps speaks volumes.

And if he claims strong to connections to powerful people, it's most likely a lie anyway. Most startup owners/CEOs I've met always lie about this kind of stuff. And don't get me wrong, I'm not saying he doesn't know these people, but these days, it's not difficult to add executives to your LinkedIn network and to pretend that they're your best friends.

> I’m planning to quit in a few months,

You need to be planning for the worse. What happens if the startup runs out of money tomorrow? or next week?

> (taken from Lacie's comment) By a few months I mean two-three months because I don't want to forfeit the end-year bonus, which won't be paid until Feb because they don't want people to just get the bonus and quit (I don't really see the logic since if they quit they quit anyways, but it's explained to me that way).

Well, I see the logic. He doesn't have the money to pay you. He won't have the money to pay you in February either. Or most likely, someone else will quit before February, he'll have a temper tantrum and he'll use that as a reason for delaying that bonus even further past February.

He's belittling you, insulting you, and he's making abrupt policy changes. To me, that just means that he'll just invent a new excuse, any excuse, not to not pay you again.

Do not disregard your feelings. Trust them. It sounds to me like he has broken his word before. Assume that he will break his word again. Get out this situation as soon as you can. Send out your resume now. Squirrel money away for rent and basic expenses. Finding a new job takes time anyway. Do not delay your search. It may even take you until February or longer to get a good offer even if you start looking now.

Answer (score 4):

*My answer assumes the US, or countries with similar labor laws*

Not sure why your plan is to wait a few months - you should start looking for a new jobs right now. Now the question is how to endure the environment, here's what I'll say:

If you can live with it for a little while longer, the best way is just to bear it and do the bare minimum that will avoid calling attention to yourself. However, for the sake of your mental health it sounds like that may not be an option for you. I think you could really benefit from setting clear boundaries around work hours - eg once you log off, you're done for the day and any communications will be answered in the morning. Or if you do any work off the clock, you will consider that overtime and expect to be paid as such. Such changes might result in pushback from management, but at the end of the day the law is on your side there.

Now if you have enough savings to comfortable live without a paycheck until you find something else, then consider just quitting now. That would be easiest for your mental health and allow you to focus all energy on the job search.

Finally, what role does publicly reviewing him/the startup have in all of this? Unless I'm missing something, you should just get a new job and get out of there with a clean start. Don't get involved in any mud-slinging, that can only drag you down.

Answer (score 3):

*"I confronted him in a team's group chat out of frustration"* - that's like breaking up via SMS (don't). You fell on a sword and now wonder why the wounds hurt?

Calling out your boss in a group space is not a great way to resolve issues or get points for professionalism and conflict resolution skills.

Recommendation:

- **Do a 1-on-1 to clear the air.** IMPORTANT: Keep your account of problems *as* *objective and de-personalized as possible*, i.e. focus on challenges and ask how you can help.

**If you want to really bring your A-game:** apologize for the chat thing, then rise above your feelings and flip the script: instead of complaining, ask what challenges the business is facing, or what the key expectations are for your team or whatever specifically your work focuses on, and ask for guidance on how you can help -- that is, try to **become part of the solution, not the problem.**

**It doesn't matter if you are going to quit -- do this anyway.** In fact, knowing you have nothing to lose should help you detach, see the issues from his perspective and offer support, even if that means stepping over your hurt feelings and putting the hurt on hold temporarily.

To be sure: do quit if you wish. But in the meantime, suck it up and focus on the work, maintain professionalism and try to bring the best version of yourself to the work. Try to minimize the personal drama and keep laser-focused on objective work-related issues to justify your decision.

When its time to go, reframe the resignation in light of your own career development, rather than an escape from a toxic environment with your boss's name on it. That way, at a minimum you won't burn bridges and will maintain a professional stance throughout the process. If he doesn't care and continues being toxic with you and others, well then, at least you will leave knowing you gave it your best shot and was able to stand up to the challenge rather than simply complain and run as soon as things got tough. Good luck!